# Are the coefficients in the stationary phase approximation computed explicitly somewhere

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, computational-number-theory

In Stein's "Harmonic analysis" book, page 334, one can find
the asymptotic expansion

[image]

An instructive proof is given for the case $k=2$. It is  clear enough to generalize to the cases $k\geq 3$. But the coefficients are not computed explicitly. It is not a matter of merely expanding the phase and amplitude. For instance, some integrals are used in obtaining the expansion. These integrals are given in terms of their asymptotics.

**Are the coefficients $a_{j}$ (the first few hopefully) computed explicitly somewhere ?**

Comment: For $k=2$ this is the whole point of the expansion into Feynman diagrams. See Chapters 2 and 3 of the course notes by Etingof https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/pages/lecture-notes/ For $k\ge 3$, explicit formulas are harder to come by. For some work in this direction see this article by Morozov and Shakirov https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2009/12/002 on what they call integral discriminants.

Comment: Thank you, but I found nothing useful in those references.

Comment: R. Wong's book "Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals" (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719260) has a few sections about this. I think It gave a way to find the coefficients (at least for $k=2$). For $k>2$, I do not have any references but I believe special cases might be known somewhere, for instance $\phi=x^3$, the book has a little related discussion for that in section VII.4.

Comment: I have in my notes that $|a_0|\simeq|\phi^{(k)}(x_0)|^{1/k}|\psi(x_0)|$ but I can not guarantee 100% that the computation was correct :D

Comment: See [$(2.3.23)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.E23) in the DLMF.

Answer (score 3):

The following is mostly adapted from [1] (I am the second co-author). Suppose
$$
\psi(x) \sim x^{-1+\beta/\rho} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_j x^{j/\rho}, \quad
\phi(x) \sim x^{s/\rho} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \phi_j x^{j/\rho} $$
where $\beta, \rho, s > 0$, $\psi_0 \ne 0$, and $\phi_0 > 0$. To address the original question, we can presumably take $\beta = \rho = 1$ and $s=k$. Under the change of variables $\tau = [g(x)]^{1/s}$, the integral transforms to
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \lambda \phi(x)} \psi(x) \; dx = \int \Psi(\tau) s \tau^{\beta-1} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \lambda \tau^s} \; d\tau $$
where
$$ \Psi(\tau) = \tau^{s-\beta} \frac{\psi(\phi^{-1}(\tau^s))}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(\tau^s))} \sim \sum_{j=0}^\infty \Psi_j \tau^j, $$
for some coefficients $\Psi_j$ given explicitly below.
An asymptotic expansion for the latter integral is readily established by repeatedly applying integration by parts. The contribution of the critical point to the integral (so an asymptotic expansion of the integral, e.g., if we assume $\psi$ has compact support and the only critical point is $x=0$) is
$$ -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\lambda}\right)^{\sigma_n} \Gamma(\sigma_n) \Psi_n 
= \lambda^{-\beta/s} \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j \lambda^{-j/k}
$$
where we define $\sigma_n = (\beta+n)/s$ and where
$$ a_n = -\mathrm{i}^{\sigma_n} \Gamma(\sigma_n) \Psi_n . $$

The coefficients $\Psi_j$ are explicitly given by
$$ \Psi_n = \frac{\rho}{s} \phi_0^{-\sigma_n} \sum_{j=0}^n \psi_{n-j} \sum_{\pi \in \Pi(j)} \binom{-\sigma_n}{\pi} \prod_{i=1}^{j} \left(\frac{\phi_i}{\phi_0}\right)^{\pi_i}.$$
Here $\Pi(n) \subseteq \mathbb{N}_0^n$ is the set of multi-indices corresponding to partitions of the integer n,
$$ \pi \in \Pi(n) \quad\text{iff}\quad \pi_1 + 2 \pi_2 + 3\pi_3 + \dotsb + n \pi_n = n, $$
and we use a nonstandard definition for the multinomial coefficient,
$$ \binom{z}{\pi} = \frac{z(z-1)\dotsm(z-|\pi|+1)}{\pi_1! \pi_2! \dotsm \pi_n!}, $$
where $|\pi| = \pi_1 + \pi_2 + \dotsb + \pi_n$.
See [1] for details of the derivation.

In particular the first few coefficients are
$$\begin{aligned}
a_0 &= -\frac{\rho}{s}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\phi_0}\right)^{\beta/s} \Gamma\left(\frac{\beta}{s}\right) \psi_0, \\
a_1 &= -\frac{\rho}{s}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\phi_0}\right)^{(\beta+1)/s} \Gamma\left(\frac{\beta+1}{s}\right) \left(\psi_1 - \frac{(\beta+1)\psi_0 \phi_1}{s \phi_0}\right), \\
a_2 &= -\frac{\rho}{s}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\phi_0}\right)^{(\beta+2)/s} \Gamma\left(\frac{\beta+2}{s}\right) \left[\psi_2 +\frac{\beta+2}{s}\left(- \frac{\psi_1 \phi_1}{\phi_0} + \frac{(1+\frac{\beta+2}{s})\psi_0 \phi_1^2}{2\phi_0^2}-\frac{\psi_0\phi_2}{\phi_0}\right)\right] . \\
\end{aligned}$$

[1] *Lyness, James N.; Lottes, James W.*, [**Asymptotic expansions for oscillatory integrals using inverse functions**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10543-009-0223-2), BIT 49, No. 2, 397-417 (2009). [ZBL1173.41014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1173.41014).